# Include Missing Dates Group By Date and Running Total

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below:

```
transID | date | payee | amount
1       | 7/1/2016 | Balance| 100.00
2       | 7/1/2016 | Bobi | -11.11
3       | 7/4/2016 | Chris | -20.76
4       | 7/7/2016 | Erin  | -100.00
5       | 7/11/2016| Tom   | -2.11
6       | 7/11/2016| Pay   | 500.00
```

I am having a issue tackling how to group by days, sum, and include the missing date. I am trying to get a select to look like this:

```
date  | balance
7/1/2016 | 88.89
7/2/2016 | 88.89
7/3/2016 | 88.89
7/4/2016 | 68.13
7/5/2016 | 68.13
7/6/2016 | 68.13
7/7/2016 | -31.87
7/8/2016 | -31.87
7/9/2016 | -31.87
7/10/2016 | -31.87
7/11/2016 | 466.02
```

Basically I am trying to get all the dates between each grouped date and carry the balance. This will operate just like a bank account does from day to day.

Comment: One option at your disposal is to create a calendar table containing all the dates you need.  It would be non trivial to try to generate the missing data from your current table.

Answer (score 1):

Just needed something like this, maybe it's not the right way, but worked for me :)

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        '2016-07-01' + INTERVAL a + b DAY myDate
    FROM
        (SELECT 0 a UNION SELECT 1 a UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) d, (SELECT 0 b UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 20 UNION SELECT 30 UNION SELECT 40) m
    WHERE
        '2016-07-01' + INTERVAL a + b DAY < '2016-08-01'
    ORDER BY a + b) t1
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS myCount, DATE(your_date_field) AS myFS
    FROM
        your_table_that_misses_dates
    GROUP BY myFS) t2 ON t1.myDate = t2.myFS order by myDate;
```

It'll give you something like this:
[image]